# show nothing if no patient had a type of diagnose

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access, visual-studio-2019

I wrote a piece of code that shows a form with all types of existing diagnoses one can encounter.
I can choose a diagnose from a combobox that will
A: display diagnose info
and
B: show all patients that had this certain type of diagnose already.

Problem: if no patients had this type of diagnose already , the values in the listbox should be "" empty.
Unfortunately it shows "code" instead of nothing.

here is my code:

```
Private Sub Diagnoses_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        Me.Tbl_DossiersTableAdapter.Fill(Me.PatientenDatabaseDataSetX.tbl_Dossiers)
        Me.Tbl_DiagnosesTableAdapter.Fill(Me.PatientenDatabaseDataSetX.tbl_Diagnoses)
        Dim dt = Tbl_DiagnosesBindingSource
        cboxDiagnose.DataSource = dt
        cboxDiagnose.DisplayMember = "Diag_Type"
        cboxDiagnose.ValueMember = "Diag_ID"
        txtDiagnoseBeschrijving.Text = dt(0)("Diag_Type").ToString
        cboxDiagnose.Focus()

    End Sub
    Private Sub CboxDiagnose_SelectionChangeCommitted(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cboxDiagnose.SelectionChangeCommitted
        txtDiagnoseBeschrijving.Text = DirectCast(cboxDiagnose.SelectedItem, DataRowView)("Diag_Beschrijving").ToString
        Dim cn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=F:\GoogleDrive\EINDWERK VBNET\PatientenDatabase.accdb")
        cn.Open()
        Dim ssql As String = "Select rel_id, tbl_Relaties.Rel_Naam &' ' & Rel_Voornaam as totaleNaam " &
            "From tbl_Relaties INNER Join (tbl_Dossiers INNER Join tbl_DossRelatie On " &
            "tbl_Dossiers.Dos_ID = tbl_DossRelatie.DR_DossID) ON tbl_Relaties.Rel_ID = tbl_DossRelatie.DR_RelID WHERE Diag_ID = " & cboxDiagnose.SelectedValue

        Dim cmmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand(ssql, cn)
        Dim dr As OleDb.OleDbDataReader
        dr = cmmd.ExecuteReader
        Bs_relaties.DataSource = dr
        If dr.HasRows Then
            Application.DoEvents()
            Bs_relaties.DataSource = dr
            lboxPat_Diagcombo.DisplayMember = "totaleNaam"
            lboxPat_Diagcombo.ValueMember = "Rel_ID"
        Else
            'lboxPat_Diagcombo.text = "" 
'this is the part where i don't know what to fill in
        End If
        cn.Close()
    End Sub
```

the value in the listbox is "system.data.oledb.oledbDataReader"
but i want to show no data if this type of diagnose has not been used, or at least a message in the box that says "no patients have had this diagnose before".

thank you for any advice or tips on this matter!

Comment: If you execute the ssql command with a Diag_Id that should return no records via the query interface in Access what do you get as a result?

Comment: Are you saying that the combo box (dropdown) should ONLY show choices for existing diagnose types in use?

Comment: the combobox should show all diagnose , the textbox will show the diagnose basic info, the listbox shows all patients with this diagnose.
if no patients are found with this diagnose, the list should be empty and not show the line "system.data.oledb.oledbDataReader"
this image could provide clarity: https://imgur.com/dn0PSiW

Comment: the query in access shows notthing?

Comment: Not sure why as I've never bound anything direct to a data reader as you're doing here.  Maybe the best solution is to use your data reader to load a DataTable object, then mind your controls to that.  Also, little aside.  Whats the reason for the Application.DoEvents call.  Always scares me a bit when I see that

Comment: Just add a where clause as a sub query somthing like WHERE  (select count(*) from tblDiagnose where diag_id = patientid) > 0 to the query that fills the results.